# Unity WebGL Build doesnt work on iOS 13 webview

Tags: unity-game-engine, safari, ios13, unity-webgl

I have  developed a game on Unity platform. Getting webgl build and deploy a server. I play the game on Android and iOS 12. But after iOS 13 update ı cant run the game on iOS webview. When I open the game link in webview, progress doesnt continue after almost %90. I am not getting any error from console. Anybody has any comment or suggestion about this topic?

Comment: This appears to be a known issue with iOS 13.  https://forum.unity.com/threads/webgl-projects-not-loading-after-ios13-update.751736/

Comment: @whydoubt thanks a lot, I will follow this link.